# Python: Showing unmet dependencies error and broken packages error despite not having any such packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-venv, openvino

We were trying to run a shell script for installing prerequistes(install_prerequistes_onnx.sh) for OpenVINO Model Optimizer but we got the following error:
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9KuL.jpg)

We tried resolving it using python 3.6.7 in a virtual environment(tsc). But it was of no use. Also **we do not have any broken packages(we checked for them explicitly) but it still shows "unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages".**

Can anyone explain the last three lines of the error? Also what does "error in line 78" imply, since our notebook was running fine before incorporating OpenVINO.

PS: We are using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that you’ve installed external software dependencies.

You may refer to this link for the installation:
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.3/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html#install-external-dependencies

For your virtual environment, the broken packages error that you’re facing is due to the Python’s dependency package version is not available on your system.

Try with this command: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

If the issue still persists, you may need to re-install Python.